# Cant getValueNames() from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I want to read all Values out of the Registry that are in the

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

I am trying to do this with the following Code:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", false);
        string[] values = key.GetValueNames();
```

But my values String is always empty.
The interesting part about that is, if I change the Code to

```
 RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", false);
        string[] values = key.GetValueNames();
```

I get the correct amount of ValueNames in CurrentVersion. Why does it not work in \Run?
If I change from LocalMachine to CurrentUser the \Run path works too.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", false);
        string[] values = key.GetValueNames();
```

Can someone tell me why my first CodeExample does not work? Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce that. Your first example works fine for me. Did you test it in a stand-alone test program? Maybe it's some strange circumstances in your real code...

Comment: Just did that. Same Problem again. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide details on whether your C# application is 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64). If the application is 32-bit running on 64-bit Windows, registry calls for `HKLM\Software` are redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`. Microsoft call this the [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(VS.85).aspx). Only certain keys are redirected, the details are in the linked article.

If your application is 64-bit, these registry calls are not redirected.

You can test this by manually adding a single REG_SZ entry of say "TestWOW" to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Your 32-bit code should read this value (even though you actually asked for another registry key!).

If you can, re-compile your application as 64-bit. Now the same code will return the expected values from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a mechanism to force Windows to NOT re-direct your registry calls to the Wow64 node for 32-bit applications running on a 64-bit OS.